In Azure Logic Apps, how do I take SQL query results that are JSON and populate an array so I can use the results is a conditional logic?
I want to use conditional logic in an Azure Logic App like,
When ID's are in this group of ID's, do some action.
The group of ID's stored in a SQL database. The SQL query results look like this:
{
  "ResultSets": {
    "Table1": [
      {
        "ID": 85
      },
      {
        "": 88
      },
      {
        "ID": 177
      }
    ]
  },
  "ReturnCode": 0,
  "OutputParameters": {}
}

If I had these values in a numeric array like [85,88,177] the conditional logic would work, I tested that.
I tried to use Parse_JSON to populate the array but the results look like ID:85, ID:88, ID:177 and didn't work in the contains function which is expecting a clean array.
How do I cleanly populate an array based on JSON?
Or, is there a way to use the sql result directly in the conditional logic?
Thanks

Can you elaborate further on the conditional logic part of your question with an example using the data you provided?

To transform your JSON –
{
  "ResultSets": {
    "Table1": [
      {
        "ID": 85
      },
      {
        "ID": 88
      },
      {
        "ID": 177
      }
    ]
  },
  "ReturnCode": 0,
  "OutputParameters": {}
}

to an array –
[ 85, 88, 177 ]

– you need to use the Select action, using the Table1 array as input, and selecting @item()?['ID']:

Result:

